# How can I export chart from excel into Latex with high quality(Overleaf)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, latex, pdflatex

Title says it all, we have data in Excel and we have found Kutools to create pdf files from tables , but it is not working for charts. We have tried export graphs into png, pdf and it has low quality after uploading into overleaf. Do you have any tool or tip which can help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Hi, it looks like you can convert an excel chart into an `.eps` file (I believe that is a vector image), and that you can import the `.eps` image into latex. This is a link that describes the process for an old version of excel:https://engineering.purdue.edu/paramnt/FAQ/SEC_Graphs_and_Displaying_Data/Q001.html and I think this is a video that shows how to do that: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MO62eXV4uVQ

Comment: You can refer to this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/88449/is-it-possible-to-put-ms-excel-graphs-into-a-latex-document

Answer (score 0):

Click File > Save As (> Browse on Office 2016 and newer).

Now select PDF under "Save as type".

Make sure "Optimise for standard" publishing is selected. Set options as required under "Options". Now click "Tools" next to save, and change "Compress pictures" to 300 DPI. Perhaps also change the DPI setting under Tools > Web options"

BTW, If you have multiple graphs each in their own sheet, hold shift and select all the sheets before doing the above.